# Javers, running in background (closed)

Tags: mongodb, javers

i need persist (insert and update) a amount data over 20k records. (using mongodb).
And all this records/entities are audited by javers and this process it is too slow.

it's possible run javers in "background" or in another thread? Or maybe some type of "tuning" the framework?

Thanks for now.

Comment: I don't think that another thread will help, do you have performance stats? What is the average commit() method latency and how many objects are you commiting at once?

Comment: All the process is completed, without commit(), in 10 seconds (almost 10k records)
Adding commit() this same process wait 25 minutes. (running in another thread)

Comment: There are some possible improvements. I've created the issue for that https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/489

Answer (score 0):

Check javers 2.9.1. This version has significant performance optimizations in MongoRepository.

Comment: Thanks, @BartekWalacik, we did the update and refactoring of ours embedded entities to persistence entities, just like a javers documentation, and we have a better performance, the same 10k records, which took 25 minutes, now are completed in 7 minutes.

Comment: So far so good. Still, 7 minutes looks like quite a long time. Could you post your commit logs with stats printed by JaVers? I mean this:
`18:34:17.441 [main] INFO  org.javers.core.Javers - Commit(id:1.0, snapshots:1, author:, changes - NewObject:1), done in 61 millis (factory:61, persist:0)`